# How do i add swipe functionality to a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a button in a view.. If I swipe it left/right, I want to be able to get the next button.. How can I do it?
Each button represents an option of a menu..

Swiping should only work on the button.

Comment: Wording of title, grammatical fixes

Comment: Am not going to write you the whole code but I love creating custom views, based on a RelativeLayout. You could create a scrollview containing the buttons in it.

Answer (score 0):

The [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) class allows you to implement horizontal swiping through menu items. It can be set up to work on just on a small area of your Activity. You would use a fragment containing just a button in your case.

Take a look at this post on the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) for an example.